# Start Another Activity within a Downloaded App

Tags: android, android-activity

I am looking to start a specific activity within another app.  I can start the Main Activity of the app using the following but I cannot seem to start the desired activity (screenshare.ScreenShareActiviy)

```
Intent i;
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        Toast.makeText(this, "ScreenCast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.glass.companion");
//            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.glass.companion.screenshare.ScreenshareActivity");
            if (i == null)
                throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  What exactly are you triyng to do?

Comment: I need to start the Screencast function of the MyGlass app.  I know that the Activity for the screencast function is screenshare.ScreenshareActivity but I'm unable to start this specific activity.  I can only start the MainActivity of the MyGlass app.

Comment: maybe this `com.google.glass.companion` application didnt have intent filter for activity launcher for ScreenshareActivity in its manifest

Comment: `getLaunchIntentForPackage(...)` does exactly what it says - it gets an `Intent` which will start the `Activity` which is the MAIN/LAUNCHER `Activity` for the package. You can't use that method to start any other `Activity` in the package. The only way you can start the `.screenshare.ScreenshareActivity` is if it has an `<intent-filter>` defined in the app's AndroidManifest.xml which has some sort of `Intent` action that can be used to implicitly start it.